# How to trigger NavigatingFrom in nested child region when parent region is navigating

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism-5

I have Nested regions

> a. ParentView/ParentRegion/ParentViewModel
>   b. Child1View/ChildRegion/Child1ViewModel
>   b. Child2View/ChildRegion/Child2ViewModel
>   b. Child3View/ChildRegion/Child3ViewModel

CASE 1: I need to have an event or trigger when Parent is navigating from which happens in ParentViewModel. But Parent is not aware of Child(s) types so If any Child is invalid I wish to prompt user to save or cancel. How to achieve this?

CASE 2:My ChildRegion is like navigating between siblings even then i need to have an event fired when Navigating From between the children and should be able to stop navigation if the current view is not valid or incomplete

My trials:
I did INavigationAware on all Parent and Child but When parent navigates child does not trigger and i have no reference to child in parent navigate from.

How do i fix this scenario?

Comment: I did something similar, but instead I allowed to navigate to different parents views while a child was open, and even to different modules. Then if the user try to close the app. instead I would navigate back to the opened view(s) if any. But I haven't found a way to tell child that a parent is navigating. Would something like this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use some version of the [observer](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) pattern here. Each child region should subscribe to an event which is triggered by the parent region in its `INavigationAware.NavigateFrom` method. Another event (or the same event, if separate functionality is not required) could be triggered by each child in its implementation of the same

Alternately, you could consider using a [CompositeCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494(v=pandp.40).aspx) instead of an event.

Comment: i thought of Observer pattern but could not figure out where to start